# How to send a html table (created by JavaScript dynamically) to PHP page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I created a HTML Table using JavaScript dynamically.

So, the number of rows are not fixed. If I click add row button, it will genarate one new row. The following HTML and JavaScript code will generate dynamic table.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    var actions = $("table td:last-child").html();
    // Append table with add row form on add new button click
    $(".add_new").click(function(){
        var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
        var row = '<tr>' +          
                    '<td><input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" ></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" ></td>' +
        '</tr>';
        $("table").append(row);     
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
    // Add row on add button click
    $(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
        var empty = false;
        var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');
        input.each(function(){
            if(!$(this).val()){
                $(this).addClass("error");
                empty = true;
            } else{
                $(this).removeClass("error");
            }
        });
        $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();
        if(!empty){
            input.each(function(){
                $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val());
            });         
        }       
    });
    // Delete row on delete button click
    $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        $(".add_new").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="display_table.php" id="my_form" name="my_form" method="post" >
            <table id='userTable' name='userTable'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>                
                <tbody>
                    <tr>                        
                        <td><input type="text" name="fname"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="lname"></td>               
                    </tr>                      
                </tbody>
            </table>
    <input type="button" id="add_new" name="add_new" class="add_new" value="Add New Row" >
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit">            
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, If I click the submit button, then the Table Data should be sent to the display_table.php page.

**display_table.php**

```
<?php
    $user_table=$_POST['userTable'];
    echo $user_table;
    #Next task is to process the table and store into MySQL Database
?>
```

If the table data is received to display_table.php then I'll process the data to store into MySQL Database.

I need help to send the HTML-JavaScript Table to display_table.php

Comment: `$_POST['userTable']` won't exist since there's not form element with that name. Tables aren't posted since it isn't a valid form element. You need to access the input fields: `$_POST['fname']` etc. Also, if you add multiple inputs with the same name, you need to pass them as arrays by naming them: `name="fname[]"` (notice the `[]` after the name). Then `$_POST['fname']` will be an array with all the inputs with that name.

Comment: You mean if I change the HTML code like this `<td><input type="text" name="fname[]"></td>` and if I change the PHP code like this `<?php
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
?>`  Then in PHP code the variable `$fname` is an array ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Yes. I understood. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understood the issue from the comments.

Now it works. I need to send the array of elements to the PHP page.

**Change in HTML code:**

```
        <tbody>
            <tr>                        
                <td><input type="text" name="fname[]"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lname[]"></td>             
            </tr>                      
        </tbody>
```

`name="fname"` will be replaced by `name="fname[]"`

**Change in JavaScript**

```
$(".add_new").click(function(){
    var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
    var row = '<tr>' +          
                '<td><input type="text" name="fname[]" ></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="lname[]" ></td>' +
    '</tr>';
    $("table").append(row);     
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

**Change in PHP code:**

```
<?php
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    echo $fname[0];
    echo '<br/>';
    echo $fname[1];
?>
```

in PHP code `$fname` is an array

**To store that table data into MySQL Database with PHP.**

(This is not relevant for the question asked. But this might be helpful for somebody.)

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "userDB");
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $fname_array=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname_array=$_POST['lname'];
    $fname_len=count($fname_array);
    $lname_len=count($lname_array);
    for($x=0;$x<$fname_len;$x++)
    {
        $fname=$fname_array[$x];
        $lname=$lname_array[$x];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user_table(fname, lname) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
        {
            echo "New record inserted successfully.";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }       
    }
    $conn->close(); 
?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!